# HTML5 local storage memory architecture?

Tags: json, html, cordova, local-storage

I have gone through many resources online but could not get the memory architecture used by HTML5 local storage. Is the data from local storage brought in memory while working over it (something like caching)?

Also in case I want to implement my app working in offline mode (basic purpose of storing into local storage), is it fine to store data as global JSON objects rather than going for local storage.

In short , I am getting a lot of JSON data while I login to my app(cross platform HTML5 app). Shall i store this data as global object or rather store it in memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it depends on how sensitive is your information and the approach you want to follow.

**Local storage**

You can use local storage for "temporal" data, passing parameters and some config. values. AFAIK local storage should be used with care in the sense that the stored information is not ensure to be there always, as it could be deleted to reclaim some device memory or cleaning process. But you can use it without much fear.

To store JSON in local storage you will have to stringify your object to store it in a local storage key. JSON.stringify() function will do the trick for you.

So far I haven´t found official information, but I think there is a limit of MB that you can store in local storage, however I Think that is not controlled directly via cordova. Again, is not official data, just take that in mind if your data in JSON notation is extremely big.

**Store data as global objects**
Storing data as global objects could be useful if you have some variables or data that is shared across functions inside the app, to ease access. However, bear in mind that data stored in global variables could be lost if the app is re-started, stopped, crashed or quit.

If it is not sensitive information or you can recover it later, go ahead and use local storage or global variables.

**Permanent storage**
For sensitive data or more permanent information I will suggest to store your JSON data in the app file system. That is write your JSON data in a file and when required recover the information from the file and store it in a variable to access it, that way if your app is offline, or the app is re-started or quit, you can always recover the information from the file system. The only way to loose that data is if the app is deleted from the device.

In my case I am using the three methods in the app I am developing, so just decide which approach will work the best for you and your needs.

Comment: Thanks a lot for a detailed reply. I can not really go for permanent storage as the data is being fetched from server dynamically. I can use Global variables, but I fear it would lead to too much code complexity. I am currently using local storage, but things I fear are that 1) is there any standred for using local storage (like what all data should be saved in local storage), 2) would it lead to a bad design pattern if I store data coming from service in local storage 3) and will it lead to a performance hit if I use local storage.

Comment: Regarding the comments, 1) AFAIK there is no guidelines or standards written in stone. It is up to you to decide how to use it. 2) Well, hard to answer, I will go for how convenient is to store the data there if it is just temporal data, if so, go ahead, if it is more sensible maybe the best thing is another option. 3) I dont think so, the access is pretty fast and does not impose a heavy duty unless you have lots of data. You can always use permanent storage and rewrite everything on each fetch.

Comment: Maybe this could help: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/11/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/ Also I am not sure about App Store process approval if Apple impose certain restrictions, I have no experience yet as the app I am developing is for private use outside the App Store. also take a look at this http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/

Comment: Thanks VicM, your comments were indeed helpful.